# How can I put a condition inside a condition in mathematica?

Tags: webmathematica, mathematica-online

The first part I programmed in python, in the second part I transcribed some parts for Mathematica

```
s1=3;
s2=-3;
s3=0;
se=5;
```

----------------------------------------- 1 part

```
If (s1>=0 and s2>=0) or (s1<0 and s2<0):
    If abs(max(s1,s2))>=se :
        print("Fail")
    else:
        print("Not fail")

Elif (s1*s2<0):
    If s1-s2>= se
        print("Fail")
    else:
        print("Not fail")
```

---------------------------- 2 part

```
If[ {s1>=0 && s2>=0} || {s1<0 && s2<0},]

If [Abs[Max[s1,s2]] >= se, Print["Fail"], Print["Not Fail"]]

If [s1-s2 >= se, Print["Fail"], Print["Not fail"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The Mathematica frontend gives us visual cues that can be used to debug our code.  One visual cue is indentation and another cue is syntax highlighting.  When we write each clause of an If-then-else on a separate line, the frontend indents the structure like this:

```
If[{s1 >= 0 && s2 >= 0} || {s1 < 0 && s2 < 0},
 If[Abs[Max[s1, s2]] >= se,
  Print["Fail"],
  Print["Not Fail"]
 ],
 If[s1*s2 < 0,
  If[s1 - s2 >= se,
   Print["Fail"],
   Print["Not fail"]]
  ]
 ]
```

Notice that each clause is indented by one space.  You won't see this if you don't start each clause on a new line.  That one space is not a character that I typed in.  The indentation happened when I used "Enter" key to start a new line.

The way it is written, your code does not produce any indenting because it is three separate If statements, not one.  But your first If does produce highlighting.  There is a red caret "^" before the last close-bracket on the first line of your code.  In general the red caret means there's a missing argument.  In this case, there is a comma  to start the "then" clause but the "then" has been left blank.  If you don't see the red caret, you must have the some or all of the highlighting turned off.  It can be turned on under Edit->Preferences->Appearance->Syntax Coloring->Errors and Warnings.

Does the above code answer your question?